# Listbox stays blank, error updating

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I have a form in visual studio, in one of the list boxes i need the users name entered into the listbox when a user is registered, i tried the following code:

```
ListBox2.Items.Add(string.Format("FirstName"));
```

But the listbox just stays blank, i've also tried the List method and that stays blank too, any ideas?

Basically nothing shows up in the list box

Comment: More context is needed. What event/method is in charge of adding the name to the listbox? This seems to work fine within a simple click event.

Comment: Well, that should work. Have you checked if the code really gets executed? Set a breakpoint on it, for example.

Comment: @RodrigoSilva what kind of break point? plus it doesnt work it just stays blank

Comment: Create a breakpoint on the code you posted in the first post, execute the program and verify if it indeed runs said code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what issue is but if it is an asp.net app you should be adding a `ListItem` not a string. See below...

```
ListBox2.Items.Add(new ListItem("FisrtName", "FirstName"));
```